What is it called when perception of a thing is replaced by an pre-existing abstraction of that thing?
Going through life, I often replace actual perception of the world with my pre-existing knowledge. If I see a car, for example, I might shortcut my understanding of it as "that is a car," and skip any further appreciation of what sets this particular car apart from the broader category of "car-ness." This is necessary, because there's too many things in the world for me to perceive all of them as they really are. I wouldn't want to spend all my time noticing paint scratches and trace amounts of rust, especially when I should be driving.
On the other hand, if I wanted to create an oil painting of a particular car, I would need to give up my pre-existing concept of what a car is, and actually see the real-life example of that concept. Otherwise, I'll end up combining details that make it through my filter with a mental image of something potentially different.
What is this called? Either the process of replacing a perception with its concept, or rejecting the mind's concept to focus on perception.
Things that I think are similar, but not quite right:

This isn't just noticing things in more or less detail. This is about wholly dismissing something I see and replacing it.
Replacing a perception with a concept seems similar to platonic Forms, but my sense of "car-ness" isn't quite an idealization of cars. It's just an accretion of personal experience with them.
Rejecting abstractions in favour of perception feels related to mindfulness. It also feels more specific, though, and I don't know enough about mindfulness to say for sure.
The reification fallacy seems closest, wherein one considers an abstraction to be real. This might be as good as I can get, but I'm wary since it seems more about artificial abstractions.


Radio personalities have a voice but no face... and you have a perception of what that person looks like. If you see the actual picture of the radio personality, then you have replaced "a perception", with reality. So the answer to your question is..."reality".

Stereotyping is something close:"One key element in the process of perception is that we connect what we are seeing to our pre-existing ideas of the world. These ideas, combined form a schema. A schema consists of the mental structures or frameworks that we use to organize knowledge and guide our cognitive processes and behavior. Schemas can perpetuate stereotypes and make it challenging for us to absorb new information and to add to our existing knowledge structures." Inclusive Perspectives.

That sounds quite close, Conifold. I'd encourage you to make that an answer.

Isn't "abstraction" the name of this process? You use the word throughout the question.

Abstraction is a useful shorthand, but since this is a more specific experience that is (probably) universal, I was sure someone had come up with a more specific term. Looks like that's the case, from the answers!

Our sensory processes do this even prior to thought.  It's called predictive coding or predictive processing - In neuroscience and cognitive science, there's an idea that our brain constantly makes predictions about what we’re going to see, based on our past experiences and memories. When we look at something, like a car, our brain doesn't just take in the visual information as it is; it guesses what the car will look like based on what we've seen before. These guesses then shape how we actually see the car. The brain compares what it expects with what’s really there and adjusts our perception to match.
At a more general perception level what you are talking about could be called constructive perception or top-down processing - In constructive perception, the brain relies on what we already know and expect to make sense of what we see and experience. This doesn't just apply to what we see but also to how we understand language, solve problems, and make decisions.
In top-down processing, our thoughts, beliefs, and expectations influence how we see and interpret the world. Our mind doesn't just react to what we sense; it mixes what we take in with what we already think and know, creating a blend of new information and existing mental patterns.
When doing art or meditating on something, if one wants a more individual image or perception, you have to focus in a less habitual way.  There's an exercise where one draws something upside down, because looking at it that way, one notices the details and the actual shapes, not the cliche prior images and expectations one has stored up already.  From Drawing on the Right Side of the Brain

Nominal Fallacy is the fallacy that giving a name is tantamount to understanding.
Also called Labelling Fallacy.
I guess you could say Reification fallacy is the special case when the label has "ontological weight". Ie most people wouldn't call "car" an abstraction until it's promoted to "carness".

Proactive interference seems close if not exactly what you’re describing. It’s a psychology term, usually about memory forming but I’d be surprised if there’s something closer.

Proactive interference (PI) refers to the reduction in memory performance for recently learned information resulting from the prior learning of related materials

Memories rely on simplifying (abstracting) to some degree. It’s perhaps less directly perceptual but you mention knowledge. And, memories are tied to our perceptions.

Kant's Transcendental Deduction in the Critique of Pure Reason might be the sort of detail you are looking for. Kant not only explains what "understanding" and "imagination" do with "perception," he also presents an argument -- the deduction -- that this ability you have related is absolutely necessary to our consciousness as such.
Rather than quote it and take up space, I would recommend A119-A121 in the regular pagination. In that particular series of paragraphs Kant is arguing that the three sources of knowing consciousness (sense, imagination, apperception or "recognition") synthetically unify a manifold that is grounded in what is given (sense, intuition), taken up by the activity of imagination, and then grasped as a unity in apperception (or recognition).
It is hard to discuss this for me in a brief note since the question if Kant is relevant to you and what you are asking is not yet known. But for Kant, perception in either inner or outer experience is what is given; this is taken up naturally into the imagination, the realm of the image; the imagination naturally accords form to what is given, in the form of the categories, which apperception then "recognizes" as an objectively valid coordination of the perceptual manifold.
Kant's model of the conscious rational subject has a lot of richness. It would say, not only does your mind wander from what is given in perception, it has every right to.
